# Object function in webpackJsonp

Tags: javascript, webpack

Im trying to reverse engineer a snippet of code that I took off webpack json min file . Now I got the code that I wanted out of the webpack but I have come across a different use of the Object function Im not familiar with .

As far as I can see there is no instance invoking on the Object or use of its prototype. 
i.e

```
let o = new Object()
```

The object keyword is used as follows

```
Object(r.a)(this, a), Object(m.a)(this, "animateToken", -1),
```

Can anyone please explain how they are using the object function .as I have not been able to find a reference to the function being used like this ... My assumption is that they have overwritten the Object function into some custom function .

Comment: `Object` is not a keyword - it's [a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object).

Comment: Updated it to a function instead of keyword